# Internal distribution of JHipster blueprints and themes

Tags: jhipster

### Q. How can the `generator-jhipster` leverage an internal distribution point, e.g., Nexus NPM, &tc. for jhipster blueprints?

#### Background

We are adopting JHipster for several major application and service initiatives building on the Java and Angular integration and tooling. We will have changes to some of the standard behaviors and will introduce an internal blueprint and a corporate theme (meeting branding standards).

What is not clear in the documentation is distribution of the blueprint and theme. Our blueprints and theme are not, naturally, suited for distribution on the JHipster marketplace.

A `.blueprint` folder is *an option* but not ideal for multiple teams and what may be many projects. `npm link` is not a shared configuration, requiring each team member, across multiple teams, working in different sprints cadences, &tc., to execute. I've given some consideration to `git submodules`, and while recently improved in Git, has dev workflow friction—and is esoteric enough—that adoption and maintenance might have to high a threshold at scale (and don't get me wrong, I loved—loved—the "vendor branch pattern" seen in SVN, coupled to SVN `export`s.)

Is there a hook into the generator to point to an internal distribution point?

Thanks!

Comment: I may have answered my question reviewing other blueprints. **1.** The JHipster Marketplace is *optional* and highlights, **not** distributes, blueprints **2.** Blueprints are NPM packages. **3.** As an NPM package, the convention prefix of `generator-jhipster-`, e.g., `generator-jhipster-myblueprint` is resolved from the public registry. **4.** Given #3, if an organization has an NPM registry, e.g., Nexus, both as a mirror and repository, `generator-jhipster --blueprint myblueprint` is resolved from the mirror, not the JHipster Marketplace. If correct, I'll promote as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I answered my own question reviewing other blueprints.

1. The JHipster Marketplace is *optional* and promotes blueprints for wide use. A blueprint may or may not desire this visibility.
2. Blueprints are NPM packages
3. As an NPM package, the "namespace" consists of the prefix `generator-jhipster-`, e.g., `generator-jhipster-myblueprint` and is resolved from a registry.
4. Given #3, if your organization has an NPM registry, e.g., Nexus, Artifactory, other, `generator-jhipster --blueprint myblueprint` resolves normally.

Feedback is appreciated.

Comment: I'm going to accept my own answer, but I have to prove it out. It looks like if you include the "custom CLI"  it enables a dev workflow that can be very powerful.